# Install Appcelerator app on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to install an Appcelerator app on a windows phone but I'm facing issues:

[ERROR] :  Failed to install app (code 2147500033)
[ERROR] :  Error: Failed to install app (code 2147500033)

Here is the current situation:

- I have installed the Windows Phone SDK 8.1
- I have a windows dev account and one unlocked device
- I have setted the JAVA_HOME environment var

I managed to install the app on the phone using the windows phone application deployment, but it only works one time! Afterwards, the app launches and then closes...

Any advices would be appreciated :-)

Thanks

Comment: By the way, the emulator is working fine

Comment: The CLI should display the actual error [since a while back](https://github.com/appcelerator/windowslib/issues/5). Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.